# Not able to access helper methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working through [RailTutorial.org](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_token), and in section 8, it has you create helper methods and use them in your controller. I am not able to access any of them

Controller line: `if current_student.admin?`
Helper method:

```
module SessionsHelper
  [...]
  def current_student
    if session[:student_id]
      @current_student ||= Student.find_by(id: session[:student_id])
    elsif cookies.signed[:student_id]
      student = Student.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:student_id])
      if student && student.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in student
        @current_student = student
      end
    end
  end
  [...]
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where and how is your helper method defined? If it's in a helper module file it should be accessible only within views.

Comment: app/helper/sessions_helper.rb

Comment: It starts with `module SessionsHelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper methods are only available within views. If you need it within views and controllers, you must define it within a controller, then declare it a helper method as well:

```
class ApplicationController
  def current_student
    # ...
  end
  helper_method :current_student
end
```

Comment: That's weird, in [the tutorial I'm following](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_token), it shows helper methods being used in controllers.

Comment: Could you explain if their is any other way?

Comment: Pretty sure that's wrong. Helper methods are best called "view helper methods". If you need this method in the controller context, define it within the controller or any parent controller.

Comment: Ok then. But by calling it a helper method in a controller, will it work in views?

Comment: Yes, `helper_method` makes the same method available within views. Saves having to put it in the helper module as well. Don't Repeat Yourself, after all.